# iText HTML Worker issue

Tags: itext

I am using iText Java API to convert HTML to PDF using the `HTMLWorker` class. I need to add a html link in a table cell, but that is giving the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper incompatible with com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph

```
<tr>
    <td width="45%">Name:Test123</td>
    <td width="25%">Date: July 2012</td>
    <td width="30%"><a href="google.com">Link</a></td>
</tr>
```

Any idea how to fix this or any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest you dump HTMLWorker, since it has been discontinued in favor of XML Worker:

- The project : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/
- The demo : http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/
- The documentation : http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. But our System is using HTMLWorker for some time and now this requirement came as an enhancement. So its not easy for us to switch at this time.I also tried simulating a table using Div and styles, but styles are ignored